# Calling a COM Interop .Net assembly from Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

We have a project running on Visual Basic 6.0
we try to migrate within Desktop Bridge.
Everything works fine, when we use DAC command prompt.
The converted application, converted as is, is working fine on any test computer.

We even managed to add a COM Interop .NET assembly to be able to use UWP features (like toasts)

Everything works fine on any dev machine, but not on a test machine.
Well, the loading of the COM Interop .Net Assembly from Visual basic seems not working.

The main difference from the test machine and dev machine :

1. On the dev machine, **Visual Studio 2017** is registering the dll as COM interop (with `regasm`, Under the Hood)
2. On the test machine, we first making a **.msi** setup file (with **Visual Studio 6 Installer**, yes the OLD one interdev style IDE ;), then we apply the DAC command line to this new .msi

So, It appears we have to register, manually, this assembly on the target test machine, with `regasm` ... since **Visual Studio 6 Installer** doesn't know how to register an interop assembly (using `regasm`)

How can we deal with that kind of scenario ?

As details we have Something straightforward :

- **MyApplication.exe** (vb6)
- **MyWrappers.dll** (and **.tlb**) (.net C# assembly marked for COM Interop AND referencing UWP SDK to be able to launch notifications)

Once again, the "installation" doesn't crash. Only the call to the COM Interop assembly for launching a toast notification.

Actually this error seems obvious if DAC didn't package this assembly for COM interop, and it make sense.

Any idea ? :)

Sebastien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will have to make the COM registration part of your package deployment.

One way to do it is to add the COM registration to your existing installer (or chain the two installers) and then run the DAC on it again.

Another option would be to "manually" add the COM registration to the DAC output that you already have (i.e. add to the registry.dat file).

A third option would be to not use COM at all, but instead use plain Win32 interop for calling UWP APIs from your VB6 app.

I have published a sample/blog post for doing the latter:
https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/02/01/adding-uwp-features-existing-pc-software/

Comment: Thx for your quick answer !
BTW :
- 1 : Not sure we can "chain" two installers : One installer from Visual Studio 6 Installer and one from Visual Studio 2017 installer. Do you have any sample doing this ?
- 2 : This solution seems completed : How can I add Something in the registry.dat file ? Well, when the appx is installing, can i add some custom action to interact with this registry.dat ? do you have any sample ?
- 3 : Is it possible from VB6 to C# assembly ? (your sample is from VB6 to C++) do you have any sample ? :)

Thx !

Comment: Option 1 is fairly simple and like the best path for your situation: you can just create a .bat file with two lines - first line calls your existing installer, second line registers the COM component. Then you point the DAC at the .bat (instead of pointing it to your installer). Btw, regarding option 2: you can load the registry.dat file into the regedit.exe in order to view and edit its content.

Comment: Thx, we finally decided to migrate the installation process to Visual Studio 2017 Installer.
By the way, if you have pointer for the option 3, i'm still interested !

Comment: If you want to use C# here, using COM interop is your best bet. However, if your C# assembly is really just a thin layer for calling UWP APIs, then going the C++ route as in my example would be more light-weight/straight-forward (imo).